# How to serve dynamic application by subdomain

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to build application like Shopify.So, users will register and get sub-domain for their store (i.e xxxxx.myShopify.com). (will build with reactjs and nodejs)

For example if there are two customers, it would be like:

**x1.myShopify.com** and **x2.myShopify.com**

How does Shopify know to serve the same react application but with **x1's** data and preferences(theme, data, products)? and do it so fast and SEO friendly?

(I guess they don't serve new instance of application for each customer and just use the same app)